# setting filters and sort by column in google spreadsheets

Tags: gdata, google-docs-api, google-sheets, gdata-python-client

I am exploring gdata python library for the purpose of uploading daily inventory reports on to google spreadsheets. I have been able to upload the csv and set the acl.

Since the staff I am sharing it with is not so gdocs savvy, I need auto filters to be applied before the spreadsheet is shared with them, so that they do not have to apply filter themselves.

I also need it to be sorted by a particular column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the google-docs-api does not contain support for the filters. You can check it out here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

From what I have learned, the api does not help with formatting cells, comments, or anything deeper than updating the contents of cells. You can create worksheets and spreadsheets, but I am not aware of anything that would be useful for your problem